# How to split the data from dataset into 2 tables depending up on particular value in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I have 1 dataset that provides the data for two Items A,B(Stored procedure will  give output of only 2 rows. One for item a and other for item b).I have to create two tables one for Items A and other for Items B. So using the same dataset I need to split Item A values into 1 table and Item B values into another table. and the SSRS report format should be like

```
No of A items in Shop                 2
No of A items in Warehouse            300
No of b items in Shop                 3
No of b items in Warehouse            340
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each table add a filter so that it only displays the item you want.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So you have two rows of data and you want two tables - one for each row?

Create the 2 tables (or better yet create one table, format it the way you want then copy it).

Add a **FILTER** to each table that restricts the first table for the **A** data using whatever field you have to tell the two types apart. In the table (tablix) properties on the **Filters** tab, click **ADD**.

For **Expression**, choose the field that has your **A** or **B** type. Change the **Value** to A on the first table and B on the second one.